# Translating Java generics to Scala

Tags: java, scala

For unit testing a Scala project, I am writing my own simple `javax.sql.DataSource` class which basically just wraps a `java.sql.DriverManager` instance under the covers.

I simply extended `javax.sql.DataSource`, and for the most part let Eclipse auto-generate stubs for the required methods/functions.

```
class H2DataSource extends javax.sql.DataSource {

  import java.io.PrintWriter
  import java.sql.DriverManager

  var printWriter : PrintWriter

  Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")

  @throws(classOf[SQLException])
  override def getLogWriter() : PrintWriter = {
    printWriter
  }

  @throws(classOf[SQLException])
  override def getLoginTimeout() : Int = {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    0
  }

  @throws(classOf[SQLException])
  override def setLogWriter(printWriter: PrintWriter) = {
    this.printWriter = printWriter 
  }

  @throws(classOf[SQLException])
  override def setLoginTimeout(seconds: Int) = {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @throws(classOf[SQLException])
  override def isWrapperFor(iface: Class[_]) : Boolean = {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    false
  }

  @throws(classOf[SQLException])
  override def unwrap[T](iface: java.lang.Class[_]) : T = {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    null.asInstanceOf[T]
  }

  @throws(classOf[SQLException])
  override def getConnection() : Connection = {
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:myH2")
  }

  @throws(classOf[SQLException])
  override def getConnection(user: String, password: String) : Connection = {
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:myH2", user, password)
  }

}
```

However, I'm running into a compilation problem with the `unwrap` function... with the compiler telling me that it doesn't override anything.

Here is a side-by-side comparison of `unwrap`... the first auto-generated in Java, and the second translated into Scala by myself.  Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, such that the compiler wouldn't recognize them as equivalent?

```
@Overrride
public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> iface) throws SQLException {
   return null;
}

...

@throws(classOf[SQLException])
override def unwrap[T](iface: java.lang.Class[_]) : T = {
  null.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

Comment: The difference is obvious. In java version the return type of unwrap is related to the type of iface but your scala version the return type of unwrap has nothing to do with the type of iface.

Comment: Thanks!  (for that second sentence, at least)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
@throws(classOf[SQLException])
override def unwrap[T](iface: Class[T]) : T = {
  null.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

Comment: Oh, duh.  I had changed `Class[T]` to `Class[_]` at some point during my experimentation, and just got so turned around mentally that I didn't change it back.